# Web scraping latest news by checking if any new news are added

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import smtplib
import time


def live_news():
    source = requests.get(
    "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/coronavirus- 
     cases-in-india-live-news-latest-updates-april6/liveblog/75000925.cms"
    ).text
   soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")

   livepage = soup.find("div", class_="pageliveblog")
   each_story = livepage.find("div", class_="eachStory")
   news_time = each_story.span.text
   new_news = each_story.div.text[8::]
   print(f"{news_time}\n{new_news}")

while(True):
    live_news()
    time.sleep(300)
```

So basically what I'm trying is to scrape latest news updates from a news website. What I'm looking for is to print only the latest news along with its time not the entire news headlines. 
With the above code I can get the latest news update and the program will send request to the server every 5mins(that's the delay I've given). But the problem here is, it will print the same previously printed news again after 5 mins if there are no other latest news updated in the page. I don't want the program to print the same news again, instead I would like to add some conditions to the program. So that It will check every 5 mins if there are any new updates or its the same previous news. If there are any new updates then it should print it otherwise should not.

Comment: add the full code

Comment: Dear Dinkan - we cannot do anything for you unless you share more insights and let us see a bit more of the code. Plz add the foll code! thx in advance

Comment: @zero Added the full code now. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I can think of is an if-statement. With the first run of your code, a variable `check_last_time` is empty and when you call `live_news()` it gets assigned the value of `news_time`.

After that, each time `live_news()` is called, it firsts check to see if the current `news_time` is not the same as `check_last_time` and if it is not, then it will print the new story:

```
# Initialise the variable outside of the function
check_last_time = [] 
def live_news():
    ...
    ...
    # Check to see with the times don't match
    if news_time != check_last_time:
        print(f"{news_time}\n{new_news}")
        # Update the variable with the new time
        check_last_time = news_time
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but sadly it doesn't work. It's still printing the same news. It looks like the global variable value isn't updating. Oh yea now I just realized how stupid I am.. variable cannot retain value when the program re-run. I must have the value in some file I assume.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer myself. I feel kinda stupid it's very simple, all you need is an additional file to store the value. Since between every execution, the variable values will get reset and so you will need an additional file to read/write data whenever you need.